# I have a tree where each node lists its ancestors instead of its descendants. Will the node with the most ancestors always be the lowest node?

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have a problem where I need to confirm that a node is at the lowest level of a tree.  Each node in the tree lists its ancestors.  Rather than doing a BFS, it seems to me that a shortcut would just be to pick the node with the most ancestors, as that will always be the node at the lowest level.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: No, you're not wrong about that, but how much work will you have in counting ancestors though?

Comment: A RIDICULOUS amount.

Comment: Can you give an example of a (non-trivial) tree and how it is represented in a data structure?

Answer (score 0):

In a tree each node has exactly one parent.
If your node stores all of it's ancestors right upto the root node, then the node with the most ancestors will be the lowest one.

However usually a node only stores the reference of its parent to reduce redundancy.

Let `Parent(X)` return the ancestor of a Node.
For the Topmost node, it returns `null`.

The level of a node can now be defined as `Level(X) = 1 + Level(Parent(X))`.